# context issue in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-context

I have problem passing context into recyclerview adapter, please see my code below. How should I make Toast work in Onclick?

I also have problem starting new activity from this Onclick

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

as startActivity is not recognized as method. Any suggestions please?

My code:

public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<Movie> moviesList;
private static final String TAG = "MyTestAppState";

Context context;

public MoviesAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> moviesList)  {
    this.context = context;
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, year, genre;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TXtitle);
        genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TXgenre);
        year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TXyear);
    }
}


public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context,"Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.v(TAG, "TEST");

        }
    });

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
    holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
    holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {return moviesList.size();
}
```

}

Comment: if the app is crashing, show your logcat and how you are creating the Recyclerview

Comment: First of all debug and check the context value you are passing. I suspect that it may be null. For toast messages you can use app context instead of activity context.

Comment: I call Main2Activity from other activity and it works fine.
Let`s concentrate on Toast only please. AFAIK problem is context.

Comment: @Michal please post your code from where you are calling your adapter...

Comment: Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Test" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: @cricket_007

wow! many thanks for suggestion. I was looking a few hours looking into recyclerview context examples, but hadn`t found this one.

Comment: Also check in your Activity if you already initialized the Context before initializing the Adapter.

Comment: @mariozawa An Activity is a Context. What is there to initialize?

Comment: @cricket_007 When you initialize your Adapter make sure you have already a value for your context. Or you can do this.

mMoviesAdapter = MoviesAdapter(getContext(), YOUR_LIST);

or you can initialize the context before that line

mContext = getContext();

Comment: @mariozawa All I'm saying is that `mContext` not necessary. Fragments use `MoviesAdapter(getActivity()` and Activities use `MoviesAdapter(YourActivity.this`

Answer (score 1):

Use `context.startActivity(intent);` instead of `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: my app crashes when I click Recycleview item.
Without Toast and Intent, Log works fine so I suppose context is a problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Make sure **Main2Activity** is added in **AndroidManifest.xml**